# Xcode 4.6 how to connect Mysql database

Tags: mysql, ios, xcode4.6

I'm sorry, but I am a beginner and do not know what to do. :D Please help me with a couple of questions.

I can't connected my apps with mysql server please help.

How I connect my iphone apps with mysql database?
What I must do in php on the website?
What I must do? 
What I must do in Xcode 4.6?

**Thank you for the effort.**

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you just want an sql database in your project just right click on it and choose new file then there go to Core Data and add a Data Model file. 
You can learn more about Core Data here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: OP is asking about connecting iPhone app to remote database. What you are suggesting is on device DB using core data.

Comment: But i need connect to remote database.

Answer (score 0):

This is usual setup:

- A *web service* which provides access to the resources.
- Client and server communicate via HTTP.

From the client point of view, the kind of database and the vendor of the database is an implementation detail of the web service. The client just sees the HTTP protocol and sends requests and handles the responses according the API defined by the web service.

Keywords you should lookup:

- `NSURLConnection` and delegates, asynchronous networking
- `NSJSONSerialization`
- RESTful web service
- JSON
- web application frameworks

For your first learning steps, this is what you should avoid/delay:

- SOAP
- WSDL
- XML